# Magento 1.9 : Set additional information tab as active

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, tabs

I want to set the tab with product attributes active, instead of description

Comment: Are you using RWD theme ?

Comment: @Pawan. No i do not!

Comment: Did you try my jQuery solution ?